# Emitir evento após fechar ngx-toastr Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, toasts

Estou usando o seguinte codigo para gerar o *poup-up toastr*

```
showSuccess() {
    this.toastr.success('You are awesome!', 'Success!', {
        onHidden: () => {
            console.log('hidden')
        },
        onCloseClick: (toastId: number) => {
            console.log('close')
        }
    });
}
```

porém nada acontece quando eu fecho o *toastr*, existe outra forma?

Answer (score 0):

Tente guardar a chamada da função em uma variável e se inscrever no Observable:

```js
const toast = this.toastr.success('You are awesome!', 'Success!', {
        onHidden: () => {
            console.log('hidden')
        },
        onCloseClick: (toastId: number) => {
            console.log('close')
        }
    });

toast.onAction.subscribe((action) => console.log(action));
```